# Getting EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION from JVM when trying to access a DLL function

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to access a third party DLL from my own DLL file I created but getting JVM memory access violation when calling my own DLL using JNI.

The third party dll I'm trying to call is cfint64.dll.  For compatibility issues I am creating my own dll to access the third party dll.

I don't know what compiler was used for third party cfint64.dll, but it is supposed to be for 64bit machines.

On my side, this is how I create my own DLL:  g++ -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o dll3minterface.dll DLL3MInterface.cpp

I know the third party dll has below function signature:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class dllCommunication */

#ifndef _Included_dllCommunication
#define _Included_dllCommunication
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     dllCommunication
 * Method:    nJavaInitInstance
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_dllCommunication_nJavaInitInstance
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);



#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The header file I created is below:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface */

#ifndef _Included_com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface
#define _Included_com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface
 * Method:    nJavaInitInstance
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface_nJavaInitInstance(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

My .cpp file that causes the memory access violation is below. Please note that the line causing error is funcCall(inJNIStr);.  If I comment out this function call , the program ends without errors.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <jni.h>       // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <iostream>    // C++ standard IO header
#include "com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface.h"  // Generated
using namespace std;

typedef int (__stdcall* initInstanceFunc)(jstring);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_artificialmedgui_coderdx_DLL3MInterface_nJavaInitInstance(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring inJNIStr) {
    // Step 1: Convert the JNI String (jstring) into C-String (char*)
   const char *inCStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, NULL);



    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\workspace\\AMI3MDLLInterface\\resources\\cfint64.dll");

  if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
    std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else{
      std::cout << "Loaded cfint64.dll library!!!!" << std::endl;
  }

  // resolve function address here
  initInstanceFunc funcCall = (initInstanceFunc)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "Java_dllCommunication_nJavaInitInstance");
     if (*funcCall != NULL) {
      funcCall(inJNIStr);
  }
  else{
      std::cout << "Function is invalid" << std::endl;
  }


       return 1; //Testing
    }
```

I am able to load the third party cfint64.dll but when calling one of its functions like this funcCall(inJNIStr); it throws below error.
Maybe I'm not passing the correct String data type from my .cpp file when calling the cfint64.dll function?  I'm not a C++ programmer, so any ideas cause of problem appreciated.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=12276, tid=11080
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (10.0.1+10) (build 10.0.1+10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.1+10, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: com.artificialmedgui.coderdx.DLL3MInterface

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17134 (10.0.17134.648)
Time: Sun Mar 24 14:15:30 2019 Eastern Daylight Time elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001421b910800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11080, stack(0x0000003371700000,0x0000003371800000)]

Stack: [0x0000003371700000,0x0000003371800000],  sp=0x00000033717ff258,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.artificialmedgui.coderdx.DLL3MInterface.nJavaInitInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)I+0
j  com.artificialmedgui.coderdx.DLL3MInterface.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+17
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), data execution prevention violation at address 0x0000000000000000


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RAX=0x00000006d0a4b6c0 is an oop
java.lang.String 
{0x00000006d0a4b6c0} - klass: 'java/lang/String'
RBX={method} {0x000001423eb204a8} 'nJavaInitInstance' '(Ljava/lang/String;)I' in 'com/artificialmedgui/coderdx/DLL3MInterface'
RCX=0x00000033717ff380 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
RDX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000033717ff258 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
RBP=0x00000033717ff2d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
RSI=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000033717ff380 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000033717fef80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000001423eb204a8} 'nJavaInitInstance' '(Ljava/lang/String;)I' in 'com/artificialmedgui/coderdx/DLL3MInterface'
R14=0x00000033717ff388 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001421b910800
R15=0x000001421b910800 is a thread
```

Comment: Did you compile all the code, your app and the dll, with the *exact same* compiler? If not, then start by doing that.

Comment: I am using the same Java compiler.  Using variable JAVA_HOME for both g++ command and to compile my Java classes.  What bothers me is that I see this on g++ command  "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32".  I know the third party cfint64.dll is supposed to be for 64bit machines.  I'll look more into that

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.  Maybe I didn't make this clear since the beginning, but my JNI DLL is calling another third party JNI DLL.  So when you call a JNI DLL from your Java code, you just need to pass the actual parameters.  The JVM Linker I guess will add additional parameters when invoking the actual DLL function.
Anyway from my DLL I just had to pass down these additional parameters that JVM linker would probably pass.

To call this second JNI DLL function:

```
Wrong:
typedef int (__stdcall* initInstanceFunc)(jstring);

Works:
typedef int (__stdcall* initInstanceFunc)(JNIEnv*,jobject,jstring);
...
funcCall(env,obj,inJNIStr);
```